Refresh Tab - Service Console (Salesforce)
Problem Statement -
We have a "Refresh Tab" in the service console, which refreshes all the standard components. There are multiple LWC custom components on my record details page, and I want to refresh all custom components on the "Refresh Tab" button. We have a refreshTab method in LWC WorkSpace API(WorkSpace API-RefreshTab), but I cannot call this method on the "Refresh Tab" button.   This method calls if I call it from some button.
We need to override the standard "Refresh Tab" with functionality to refresh custom components.Could someone please help me fix this issue? I am unsure whether we can override the "Refresh Tab" via LWC or Aura.
enter image description here
